# How to avoid Apache mod rewrite endless redirects?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess is very simple:

`Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^qmind/themen/([^/]*)/$ /qmind/themen/t/?art=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^qpodcast/podcasts/([^/]*)/$ /qpodcast/podcasts/?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^qmind/artikel/([^/]*)\/$ /qmind/artikel/?id=$1 [L]`

The last two Rules works perfectly but the first one causes an Internal-Error.
Apache shows: `Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.`
but I can't find my mistake.

Apache Error-Log says also `Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.` but I don't no how.

Thx for help!

Comment: Can you provide an example of a URL that you want the first RewriteRule to match and also what you want it to redirect to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^qmind/themen/([^/]*)/$ /qmind/themen/t/?art=$1 [L]
```

lets take an example

```
qmind/themen/test
```

This runs as

```
qmind/themen/test
qmind/themen/t/art=test
qmind/themen/t/art=t
```

and then repearts the bottom one as the URL matches itself

You need to write the rule to accept `/t/` as valid and not rewrite it

```
RewriteRule ^qmind/themen/([^/]*)/$ /qmind/themen/t/index.php?art=$1
```

should work as it no longer matches the original regex